# Tutorial for HTML5 drag&drop - sortable list

Tags: javascript, html

Do anyone know a really good tutorial for HTML5 drag&drop? Im making a toDo-list and I want to be able to reorder/sort it with this API. I've been googling for it like a mad man and now im start giving up... ANY tips is welcomed!
Thanks!

p.s I really want to use html5 drag&drop API, not jQuery-sortable()

Comment: Why not just look this up? The first result in Google covers everything you need...

Comment: I have. But i just cannot find a good one that explains the basics in a GOOD way. (yes im quite new to javascript)

Comment: It's still surprisingly difficult to find this information. It's 2018, are we still using jQuery-sortable everywhere?? There are plenty of HTML5 drag and drop tutorials, but nothing covering reordering.

Comment: I realize that this is an incredibly old thread, but please note that comments such as "Why not just look it up? The first result in Google covers everything you need" are not only unhelpful, but ironically this is now the first result on Google. That should suggest that the information was not as prevalent as the commenter thought.

Answer (score 83):

I've tried to keep this sample as simple as possible.

If you create a HTML list:

```
<ul>
  <li draggable="true" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">Apples</li>
  <li draggable="true" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">Oranges</li>
  <li draggable="true" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">Bananas</li>
  <li draggable="true" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">Strawberries</li>
</ul>
```

...and the following javascript:

```
var _el;

function dragOver(e) {
  if (isBefore(_el, e.target))
    e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(_el, e.target);
  else
    e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(_el, e.target.nextSibling);
}

function dragStart(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", null); // Thanks to bqlou for their comment.
  _el = e.target;
}

function isBefore(el1, el2) {
  if (el2.parentNode === el1.parentNode)
    for (var cur = el1.previousSibling; cur && cur.nodeType !== 9; cur = cur.previousSibling)
      if (cur === el2)
        return true;
  return false;
}
```

... you should get a sortable list.

You can try the code on https://codepen.io/crouchingtigerhiddenadam/pen/qKXgap

Please be aware of the following bug in FireFox:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragenter

Hope this helps.

Comment: Adding `e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)` to dragstart event made it work on firefox

Comment: I am looking exactly like this but  This is not working in mobile and Ipad. how can we make this for mobile device also???

Comment: You could use 'touchstart'. As far as the browser is concerned, touch events and mouse events should be separate. If you have a hybrid laptop, you will have both a mouse and touch input.

However, I have found on some desktop browsers, strange things happen when you use the touchmove event. For example, the object can fly off the screen when you click it with a mouse.

One day I am sure the specifications will settle down and everything will work correct. We're just not quite there yet.

Comment: What is the purpose of the isBefore() function?  It's iterating through all the previous siblings to see if the current dragged item is in it?   Please explain...

Comment: `cur.nodeType !== 9` can instead be `cur.nodeType !== Node.DOCUMENT_NODE` for readability..

Answer (score 7):

For a beginning to end tutorial, check this out: http://taximeeting.tumblr.com/post/26539340142/lightweight-jquery-plugin-for-html5-sortable-lists.

It's based on `html5sortable`: http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/. Another great tutorial on HTML5's drag and drop can be found here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/.

Comment: Author is not willing to deal with jQuery dependencies. - "not jQuery-sortable()"

Comment: None of these links work anymore.

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking to do this with table rows you need to make a slight change:

https://jsfiddle.net/cmpenney/6rx6u2kf/

```
<table>
    <tr draggable="true" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)">
        <td style="border: 1px solid black">Apples</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black">A-Column2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr draggable="true" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)">
        <td style="border: 1px solid black">Oranges</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black">O-Column2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr draggable="true" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)">
        <td style="border: 1px solid black">Bananas</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black">B-Column2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr draggable="true" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)">
        <td style="border: 1px solid black">Strawberries</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black">S-Column2</td>
    </tr>
</table>



var source;

function isbefore(a, b) {
    if (a.parentNode == b.parentNode) {
        for (var cur = a; cur; cur = cur.previousSibling) {
            if (cur === b) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function dragenter(e) {
    var targetelem = e.target;
    if (targetelem.nodeName == "TD") {
       targetelem = targetelem.parentNode;   
    }  

    if (isbefore(source, targetelem)) {
        targetelem.parentNode.insertBefore(source, targetelem);
    } else {
        targetelem.parentNode.insertBefore(source, targetelem.nextSibling);
    }
}

function dragstart(e) {
    source = e.target;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're going with the solution by **adamf** (Mar 10 '15 at 11:16), and want to use it on table rows, replace the *dragenter* function to the following:

```
function dragenter(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    while (target.parentNode.tagName != 'TBODY') {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }

    if (isbefore(source, target)) {
        target.parentNode.insertBefore(source, target);
    }
    else {
        target.parentNode.insertBefore(source, target.nextSibling);
    }
}
```

This way the target will only apply for TR elements, and not any of their child elements.

The same thing would apply for *ul > li* strunctures, if the *li* elements have children.

If there are *img* child elements, add a *draggable="false"* attribute to each.